# Why do my list items overlap?

Tags: html, css

I want my list items to be displayed next to each other but for some reason they always overlap. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```css
#background {
  height: 1000px;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/33045/lion-wild-africa-african.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  overflow: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why `position: fixed` on the `li`s?

Comment: That's the mistake, remove `position: fixed` on the `li`s

Comment: I tried different positions to see if they'll change anything, forgot to delete that

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove position: fixed in 'li' element, because if you giving every 'li' element position fixed that will make your item always overlap.
May be you can try update your 'ul' and 'li' element style like this code bellow:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    overflow: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have define `position: fixed` for `li` tags.

```css
#background {
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/33045/lion-wild-africa-african.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: white;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    overflow: none;
    //position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                    <li>Item 5</li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `position: fixed`. This fixes an element within the browser viewport and removes it from the flow. Not what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> **fixed**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Answer (score 0):

give position fixed to ul and you will get list item properly

```css
#background {
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/33045/lion-wild-africa-african.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: white;
        position: fixed;
        padding:5px;
        
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    overflow: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                    <li>Item 5</li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```